# Component Links not working in 64 bit mode

Tags: tridion

**Brief Summary:**
We are using Tridion 2009 SP1, however we never used .NET templating, we are still using R5 concept i.e. (VBScript, XSLT etc), we are using broker database for our linking etc.

Our Tridion Server/Presentation Server/services are running perfectly on 32 bit environment/mode, our IIS is running on 32 bit mode. Everything is running perfectly.

**Problem:**
We recently decided to move all our server to 64 bit mode, so now everything moved to 64 bit (IIS, Tridion Server/Services etc), everything is working perfectly except the Component Links. Due to that we again moved our Tridion services to 32 bit mode as well as IIS to 32 bit mode and then component links start working

**Error:**
When all the things are running on 64 bit mode, we are getting component link resolving error and getting below error when it trying to resolve the component.

```
Error Failed to resolve component uri tcm:233-218990 while called from ComponentLink.ResolveLink on /english/index.aspx
... EGIT.CCIT.Tridion
... Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
... at EGIT.CCIT.Tridion.COM.ComponentLink.GetLink(String pageURI, String componentURI, String componentTemplateURI, String attributes, String text, Boolean textOnFail, Boolean anchor)
... at EGIT.CCIT.Tridion.Broker.LinkResolver.ComponentUrl(String pageUri, String uri, String componentTemplateUri, String publicationUri)
...
09:50:58.90 Error Error in Core Tridion call
... netrtsn
... Attempt to load JVM failed on native side
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.Load(Boolean bAcceptPreloaded)
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.Load()
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr()
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle()
... at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
... at Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
... at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
... at EGIT.CCIT.Tridion.COM.ComponentLink.GetLink(String pageURI, String componentURI, String componentTemplateURI, String attributes, String text, Boolean textOnFail, Boolean anchor)
```

Please suggest!!

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Manu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manu,

You *can* use VBScript templates (thought it is a good idea to start moving off this platform anyway) in your CMS backend and 64-bit on the front end, if your front end is .NET or Java.

What you cannot do is use COM on the Front-end (even if being called from .NET) and be on 64 bit, since the Tridion COM-based linking API is 32 bit only.

The .NET linking libraries and the Java linking libraries are 32 and 64 bit compatible, but not the COM libraries.

Hope this helps

N

Answer (score 2):

Which version Java did you install on the presentation server? Is it 64-bit? Try the 32-bit version of Java. Otherwise try the 64-bit version.

Comment: Its working fine with 32 bit java, however our problem is that we want to run it on 64 bit mode and having ASP/VBScript and COM linking we cannot use 64 bit mode. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is the xmogrt.dll. There seems to be 2 versions of this file, one for 64-bit and one for 32-bit Java. They differ greatly in size. (+-1,30MB vs +-800KB). Which version do you have?

Comment: BTW, you can have all the COM and VBScript windows parts work in 64 bit mode, but the Java version seems to be working better when you have the 32-bit version.

Comment: Hi Kah, The above solution we have already implemented, however my requirement was that, I need everything in 64 bit environment, well I have checked in Tridion Forums and found that if you are using Classic ASP/VBScript for templating and using COM concept for resolving the links, then it would not work in 64 bit environment. So I have decided to move everything to .NET Templating. Lets see when it can be done...well thanks for your help and time!! Cheers

Comment: @MS: you do understand that there is no relation between your choice of template paradigm (vbscript vs modular) and the choice of delivery platform (asp/vbscript vs Asp.NET)? Your problem lies with delivery, not templating.